# wxSmith Code::Blocks Hello World errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I have got a problem!

I recently read through codeblocks' tutorial of how to make GUI programs with wxSmith...
To try the simple Hello World Program, I downloaded the precompiled wxPack and installed it.

But now, when i start a new wxWidgets project in Code::Blocks, it gives me thousands of errors!
I tried it a few times but I don't know what I did wrong!

[screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh0Cs.png)

And it says that there are more errors!
Can you tell me what to do?
Did I install it the wrong way?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: You should paste the *first* *few* of the errors in your message instead of showing not very informative screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste the complete build log [anywhere](http://paste.org.ru)?
Possible reasons:

- Linker can't find libs or include files (add wxWidgets\include to the list of include dies, wxWidgets\lib\vc_lib (or vc_dll) to the linker settings)
- Your project is compiled with static CRT, wxWidgets libs with dynamic (or vise versa) - you need to use same settings.
- non-wxWhdgets libs are missing (you will need to find which libs contain missed functions and add them)
- You didn't implement some methods of classes which you use in your app (you will need to add bodies for these methods)